# Using Objectify For retrieving from Datastore- Error :Did you forget to inherit required module

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt2, objectify

I am using Objectify for retrieving data From datastore in GWT,But i get the Following Error :

> [ERROR] No source code is available for type
>   com.logins.entity.experts; did you forget to inherit a required
>   module?

I have Client->entity->Server and i did define the RPC properly with RemoteServicePath.
i intiaized the Rpc in client side

> final findexpertAsync
>   finexp=(findexpertAsync)GWT.create(findexpert.class);

GWT compiler throws Error at the method i call,

```
finexp.expert(expnam, new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<experts>>()

Note:
```

1)  findexpert and FindexpertAsync are the RPC interface which has a method for retriving data from datastore
2)com.logins.entity.experts:experts is a server class.

Any guesses where i am going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All classes directly or indirectly referenced from the client must be part of the client source path.  You can't access server-only code from GWT.  In this case, class "experts" needs to be part of the GWT-compiled client code.

Also: You should capitalize Java class names.

Comment: Another common approach is to have a `shared` package, like `server` and `client`, but code that must be available to both. This helps to keep it clear what components use which classes.

Comment: Yup,I did not share the classes nor i did include in client side,thank you for letting me know :)